# Problem in passing value from child window to parent window in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm simply trying to pass value from child window to parent window. Here's my code -

**parent.php**

`<html>
    <form name="testform" id="div" method=post>
         <input type="text" name="testText">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=window.open("http://aiworker2.usask.ca/passgui/child.php","Ratting","toolbar=1,status=1,")>click</a>

    </form>
</html>`

child.php
`<html> <script langauge="javascript"> function post_value(){ opener.document.testForm.testText.value = "hello"; self.close(); } </script> <input type="button" value="Pass Value" onclick="post_value();"> </form> </html>`

Problem is, it opens the child window but whent I press the button to pass value to parent window it does not do enything. From my firebug, I have found giving an error - Permission denied. I tried from Safari as well, still not working.

Demo can be found here -

http://aiworker2.usask.ca/passgui/parent.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `name` of your `form` to `testForm`.